# How to extract catalog name from connection string using TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, pattern-matching

Say I have the following string value:

```
declare @cs nvarchar(100) = 
   'Data Source=server\instance;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True';
```

What is the T-SQL to extract the string `MyDatabase` from `@cs`?

Alternately, what T-SQL function(s) should I look at for a means to figure it out for myself?

Comment: It will be a huge disgusting substring.  String parsing in SQL is a pain.  Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: one table has the connection string and is used by client code to connect to the database, another table has the database names only because it's used to generate report views spanning multiple catalogs on the same instance... considering it's not easy, I'll probably figure out something other than the INSERT trigger I was trying to make just now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty and i'm sure you could do this faster using regex / clr patindex & substrings, but a very quick and easy way is to use the split functions below to do something like this:

**Example Usage:**

```
DECLARE @cs NVARCHAR(100) = 'Data Source=server\instance;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True';

SELECT  id ,
        Data ,
        dbo.fnParseString(2, '=', Data)
FROM    dbo.fnc_Split(@cs, ';')
WHERE   Data LIKE '%Initial Catalog%'
```

**Returns:**

```
2        Initial Catalog=MyDatabase        MyDatabase
```

As for the split functions, the first splts strings into tables, and the second splits strings into columns:

**Split into tables:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnc_Split
    (
      @Data VARCHAR(2000) ,
      @Sep VARCHAR(5)
    )
RETURNS @Temp TABLE
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Data NVARCHAR(100)
    )
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Cnt INT
        SET @Cnt = 1
        WHILE ( CHARINDEX(@Sep, @Data) > 0 ) 
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO @Temp
                        ( data
                        )
                        SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Data, 1, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @Data) - 1)))
                SET @Data = SUBSTRING(@Data, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @Data) + 1, LEN(@Data))
                SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
            END
        INSERT  INTO @Temp
                ( data )
                SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Data))
        RETURN
    END
GO
```

**Split into columns:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnParseString
    (
      @Section SMALLINT ,
      @Delimiter CHAR ,
      @Text VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NextPos SMALLINT ,
            @LastPos SMALLINT ,
            @Found SMALLINT

        --#### Uncomment the following 2 lines to emulate PARSENAME functionality
        --IF @Section > 0 
        --    SELECT  @Text = REVERSE(@Text)

        SELECT  @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, 1) ,
                @LastPos = 0 ,
                @Found = 1

        WHILE @NextPos > 0
            AND ABS(@Section) <> @Found 
            SELECT  @LastPos = @NextPos ,
                    @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @NextPos + 1) ,
                    @Found = @Found + 1

        RETURN  CASE
            WHEN @Found <> ABS(@Section) OR @Section = 0 THEN NULL
            --#### Uncomment the following lines to emulate PARSENAME functionality
            --WHEN @Section > 0 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END))
            WHEN @Section > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END)

            ELSE SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END)
        END
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

you might find this to be a lot easier, just change the from_table to your table and the connection string field to your field.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([ConnectionString], CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', [ConnectionString]) + LEN('Initial Catalog='), 100), 0, CHARINDEX(';', SUBSTRING([ConnectionString], CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', [ConnectionString]) + LEN('Initial Catalog='), 100)))
AS DbName
FROM [from_table]
```

i assume after taking the strings you might want to do something like this:
(iteration over the names and query some dbs)

```
DECLARE @DbName varchar(max)
DECLARE @QaQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([ConnectionString], CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', [ConnectionString]) + LEN('Initial Catalog='), 100), 0, CHARINDEX(';', SUBSTRING([ConnectionString], CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', [ConnectionString]) + LEN('Initial Catalog='), 100)))
AS Connections
FROM [ConnTable]

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @DbName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    --PRINT @DbName
    SET @QaQuery = N'SELECT TOP 10 [RecordID],[SomeStuff]
                        FROM ['+@DbName+'].[dbo].[SomeTable]
                        WHERE [SomeStuff] IS NOT NULL'
  EXEC sp_executesql @QaQuery;
  FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @DbName
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```